# How to maximize generalized Rayleigh ratio

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

The generalized Rayleigh ratio is defined by

$$R(\vec{x})=\frac{\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}}{\vec{x}^TB\vec{x}}.$$

The vector $\vec{x}$ is a $p \times1$ unitvector, the matricies $A$ and $B$ have the size $p \times p$. Additionally $A$ is positive semi definit and $B$ is positive definit.

How can I maximize this expression?
I tried to rewrite the lower term as a inverse matrix and then use the external definition of the gradient, but that did not work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha &= x^TAx \cr
 \beta  &= x^TBx \cr
 R &= \lambda = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \cr
}$$
Then take the gradient of $\lambda$ (with respect to $x$) and set it to zero 
$$\eqalign{
 \nabla\lambda & =\frac{\beta\,\nabla\alpha-\alpha\,\nabla\beta}{\beta^2} = 0 \cr
 \beta\,\nabla\alpha &= \alpha\,\nabla\beta \cr
 \nabla\alpha &= \lambda\,\nabla\beta \cr
 2Ax &= 2\lambda\,Bx \cr
B^{-1}Ax &= \lambda\,x
}$$
So the maximum value of $R$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $B^{-1}A$.

Comment: Very clear explanation:). Thank you alot.

Comment: @ MrYouMath . In fact, you did not understand...  It remains to show (or to admit) that the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$ are real $\geq 0$; to prove that is nearly equivalent to give an explicit invertible $P$ s.t. $A=P^TDP,B=P^TP$.