# Maximizing generalized Rayleigh quotient with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrices with real entries and let $k \geq 2$ be an integer.

I want to find the maximum of
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{\mathrm T}\,A\,X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^{\mathrm T}\,B\,X_i} $$
where the unknowns $X_i$ are vectors, under the constraints that the $X_i$ are normalized ($X_i^{\mathrm T}\,X_i = 1$ for all $i$) and orthogonal ($X^{\mathrm T}_i\,X_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$).

The problem I am facing (and that is why I add the orthogonal constraints) is that, classically, one will get the eigenvectors of $B^{-1}\,A$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433484/how-to-maximize-the-generalized-rayleigh-quotient-when-both-numerator-and-denomi) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769712/how-to-maximize-generalized-rayleigh-ratio)) but there is no reason that these eigenvectors will be orthogonal (since $B^{-1}\,A$ has no reason to be symmetric). Maybe I am missing something...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $B$ p.s.d., note that $B^{-\frac 1 2} A B^{-\frac 1 2}$ is symmetric, so it has $n$ eigenvectors $y_1,\dots,y_n$ that are orthogonal.
Then if you consider $x_i=B^{-\frac 1 2}y_i$, then $x_1,\dots x_n$ are $n$ eigenvectors of $B^{-1}A$:
$$B^{-1}A x_i = B^{-\frac 1 2} \left ( B^{-\frac 1 2} A B^{-\frac 1 2}\right)B^{\frac 1 2}x_i = \lambda_i B^{-\frac 1 2}y_i=\lambda_i x_i$$
Those eigenvectors are *not* orthogonal w.r.t. the regular inner product. That's because:
$$x_i^Tx_j = y_i^TB^{-\frac 1 2}B^{-\frac 1 2}y_j=y_i^TB^{-1}y_j$$
But they are orthogonal under the inner product defined by $B$:
$$x_i^TBx_j = x_i^TB^{\frac 1 2}B^{\frac 1 2}x_j=y_i^Ty_j$$

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly, in PCA, we get eigenvectors that are orthogonal not with the regular inner product but with the inner product defined by $B$?

Comment: For the regular PCA, matrix $A$ is the covariance matrix of your (mean-centered) data set, and matrix $B$ is the identity. So your eigenvectors are orthogonal with the regular inner product.